# How to make two microservices listen on same port in azure service fabric

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, port, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I have created a project with two microservices and want both of them to listen to same port.
I have two separate ServiceManifest File in which i have defined same endpoint for both of them but when i deploy it locally or remotely it doesn't work.

When I deploy it locally it shows following Exception:
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the "port number same in ServiceManifest.xml file for both the Microservices."

Just make the URL different for different services

For Ex localhost:8100/service1/....
 localhost:8100/service2/....

"Different appRoot for different services"

Comment: and how do you do that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57564493/how-do-you-set-up-two-microservices-that-both-use-https-port

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the communication stack you are using you have a few options.

If HTTP based web API - you can use the reverse proxy and dynamic port assignment for the services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy

If using Service Remoting - just use dynamic ports.

For external communication to the cluster - taka look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy#special-handling-for-port-sharing-services